# Can anyone explain the following code?

Tags: css

I am unable to understand especially in background property.

```
 .stars div a {
      background: transparent url(sprite_rate.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 23px;
      width: 12px;
      text-indent: -999em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for editing.. i forgot it

Comment: Mihir, you should start searching for answers before asking them straight away. You should put the url in quotes like this - 'sprite_rate.png'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS background property is a shorthand property of the following properties below:
The order of the property values for the CSS background property are:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

It does not matter if one of the property values is missing, as long as the ones that are present are in this order.

In your case you're doing the following:

```
background: transparent url(sprite_rate.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

**transparent**

That means that the background color is transparent

**url(sprite_rate.png)**

The url of the background image is sprite_rate.png.

**0 0**

The left and top position is 0px.

**no-repeat**

The last parameter is no-repeat which means the image will not repeat on the x- and y- axis.

Here's link to all the properties in correct order:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-color.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp

You can read more about the background shorthand property at:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
background:
```

`transparent` *hope it's clear :)*

`url(sprite_rate.png)` a background image

`0 0` a position in the container - left top corner

`no-repeat` the background image shouldn't repeat

```
display: inline-block;
```

a box behaving like an inline element, see http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

```
height: 23px;
width: 12px;
```

size of an element

```
text-indent: -999em;
```

kicks the element far beyond the visible area, http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-indent.asp

```
overflow: hidden;
```

hides the content that doesn't fit in the element, http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the `background` CSS shorthand property is:

```
background: { background-color background-image background-repeat background-attachment background-position | inherit } ;
```

It combines a large number of background properties into a single shorthand property. See:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background for more information.

The technique you're looking at is known as **CSS Sprites**. You can find more information about it here:

- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 0):

Draws the top-left corner of sprite_rate.png over an otherwise transparent background without repeating (tiling) the image. It will be displayed inline (between text) but act as a block and will be 12 pixels wide and 23 pixels high. The first line of text will be indented so far to the left that most likely none of it will be visible, especially since overflow will be hidden (nothing outside the 12x23 rectangle will be rendered).

All of that could have been googled.